# iOS resize textfield in toolbar when button width changes

Tags: ios, uitextfield, uitoolbar, uibaritem

I still stuck in fixing my code for iOS 7.1 with the new option "button shapes". Selecting it is increasing the width of an `UIButtonItem` in my programmatically created toolbar. This will move an text field to the right because I do not know how to get the (changing) available space in the toolbar to set the width for the textfield.

[image]  [image]

I tried to get the button size with `customItem.customView.frame.size.width);` but it will always return "0.0".

I need to create the toolbar with button and textfield programmatically in order to provide the textfield. But until now I hard coded the textfield width (210) to fit it in the available space next to the button (too bad I know). I can't find a way to get the size of the button to fit the text field size nor do I find a solution to resize the textfield based on the "button shape" option.

What can I do? Thanks.

```
[self.navigationController setToolbarHidden:NO]; //animated:YES
[self.navigationController.toolbar setBarTintColor:[UIColor colorWithRed:0.8f green:0.0f blue:0.0f alpha:0.5]];
[self.navigationController.toolbar setTranslucent:YES];

// button
UIBarButtonItem *customItem = [[UIBarButtonItem alloc] initWithTitle:@"Simulation" style:UIBarButtonItemStylePlain target: self action: @selector(prepareResultView:)];

// text field
CGRect frame = CGRectMake(0, 0, 210, 30);
numberText= [[UITextField alloc] initWithFrame:frame];
numberText.autoresizingMask = UIViewAutoresizingFlexibleWidth;
numberText.borderStyle = UITextBorderStyleRoundedRect;
numberText.textColor = [UIColor blackColor];
numberText.font = [UIFont systemFontOfSize:18.0];
numberText.contentVerticalAlignment = UIControlContentVerticalAlignmentCenter;
numberText.textAlignment = NSTextAlignmentCenter;
numberText.placeholder = NSLocalizedString(@"Anzahl Berechnungen", @"Message");
numberText.backgroundColor = [UIColor whiteColor];
numberText.autocorrectionType = UITextAutocorrectionTypeNo;
numberText.keyboardType = UIKeyboardTypeNumbersAndPunctuation;
numberText.returnKeyType = UIReturnKeyDone;
numberText.clearButtonMode = UITextFieldViewModeWhileEditing;
numberText.delegate = self;

[numberText  setRightViewMode:UITextFieldViewModeAlways];

// textfield item
UIBarButtonItem *customItem1 = [[UIBarButtonItem alloc] initWithCustomView:numberText];// behavior of number textfield see below

NSArray *items = [NSArray arrayWithObjects: customItem, customItem1, nil];
[self setToolbarItems:items animated:YES];
```